# How to traverse a multi tree in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.Net and I am stuck at one issue. I have a multi tree. Root has many children and even those children have many other children. I want to traverse the multi-tree using recursion. I could not find much information online. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Below is what I want to achieve:

**My Object that I need to send via REST**:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

<DataContract>
Public Class DropdownObj

    <DataMember(Name:="name")>
    Private dropdownData As String
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return dropdownData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            dropdownData = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <DataMember(Name:="id")>
    Private _id As Integer
    Public Property id() As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As Integer)
          _id = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

**Actual REST:**

```
tmpGroups = SMS_Logic.Group.LoadGroupsForCombo(_currentUser.dsDir().Group, _currentUser.dsDir().Group_Group, _currentUser.dsDir().Location)

    Dim x As Integer
    x = tmpGroups.Count()
    Dim temp As New List(Of DropdownObj)
    For objCount As Integer = 0 To tmpGroups.Count - 1
        Dim xobj As New DropdownObj
       xobj.name = tmpGroups(objCount).Description
        xobj.id = tmpGroups(objCount).GroupID
        temp.Add(xobj)
        Console.WriteLine(tmpGroups(0).Description)
    Next
    Return temp
End Function
```

So **tmpGroups** has all the root and then branches out to children. I need only some values out of it and obviously I need to traverse to get these values. After getting these values I need to send them to the front end as REST Service. Currently, In the above code, I could only get all the roots when I used only one loop. But its a tree strcuture and I need to traverse all of that and correspondingly add the values to new tree or something which I can pass to my front end.

Comment: Please show us what you've done to try and solve the problem.

Comment: I have added some code snippet of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Something you should do on your own, but here it is anyway.
I say this because whenever I learn a new language, recursification is probably the first thing I try to implement and it's exciting and encouraging when I accomplish it.

```
Private Shared Sub HandleNode(ByVal node As Object)
    'Do the work on the node before child-nodes.

    For Each child As Object In node.Children
        HandleNode(child)
    Next

    'Do the work on the node after child-nodes.
End Sub
```

It might matter if you do your work on the current node before or after it's children. Something to keep in mind.

Comment: I have added my code snippet. Can you look at it once, Many thanks!

Comment: It will iterate multi tree too? I mean if a root has many child. and even those child has many child in return. Kindly guide.

Comment: @Unbreakable : Yes it will. The method that RoyalPotato provided iterates through every child _in the current node_, then it calls the method again _on each of those children_. So it will do the same for every child and its children until there are no more.